# How to modify method return value in all derived classes?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns

Imagine you have a class hierarchy as:

```
class Base
{
    public virtual string GetName()
    {
        return "BaseName";
    }
}

class Derived1 : Base
{
    public override string GetName()
    {
        return "Derived1";
    }
}

class Derived2 : Base
{
    public override string GetName()
    {
        return "Derived2";
    }
}
```

In most appropriate way, how can I write the code in a way that all "GetName" methods adds "XX" string to return value in derived class?

For example:

```
         Derived1.GetName returns "Derived1XX"

         Derived2.GetName returns "Derived2XX"
```

Changing the code of GetName method implementation is not good idea, because there may exist several derived types of Base.

Comment: This is usually not a good design. If you don't want something to be changed in the children, make it `sealed`.

Comment: @Renan methods are sealed by default, they must be `virtual` to be overridable. If the class is `sealed`, there can be no children. And OP does want `GetName` to return different things in each child - he just wants a common suffix.

Comment: @Blorgbeard true.dat. I had completely forgotten.

Comment: @Renan Actually I just [noticed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645769.aspx) that you *can* actually seal methods when you override them, so that they can't be overridden any further. But it's only allowed on overrides of virtual methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Leave `GetName` non-virtual, and put the "append XX" logic in that function. Extract the name (without "XX") to a protected virtual function, and override that in the child classes.

```
class Base
{
    public string GetName()
    {
        return GetNameInternal() + "XX";
    }

    protected virtual string GetNameInternal() 
    {
        return "BaseName";
    }
}

class Derived1 : Base
{
    protected override string GetNameInternal()
    {
        return "Derived1";
    }
}

class Derived2 : Base
{
    protected override string GetNameInternal()
    {
        return "Derived2";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a good use case for the decorator pattern. Create a decorator that has a reference to a Base:

```
class BaseDecorator : Base
{
    Base _baseType;

    public BaseDecorator(Base baseType)
    {
        _baseType = baseType;
    {

    public override string GetName()
    {
        return _baseType.GetName() + "XX";
    }
}
```

Construct a BaseDecorator with your chosen class (Base or Derived), and call GetName on that.

Comment: This seems like a good solution. Another pattern that could be applied is the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to (or can't) modify original classes, you can use extension method:

```
static class Exts {
    public static string GetNameXX (this Base @this) {
        return @this.GetName() + "XX";
    }
}
```

You'll be able to access new method as usual:

```
new Derived1().GetNameXX();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split the construction of the name into various overridable parts and then override each part in each of the different subclasses.
Below is one such example.

```
public class Base {
  public string GetName() {
    return GetPrefix() + GetSuffix();
  }
  protected virtual string GetPrefix() {
    return "Base";
  }
  protected virtual string GetSuffix() {
    return "";
  }
}

public class DerivedConstantSuffix : Base {
  protected override string GetSuffix() {
    return "XX";
  }
}

public class Derived1 : DerivedConstantSuffix {
  protected override string GetPrefix() {
    return "Derived1";
  }
}

public class Derived2 : DerivedConstantSuffix {
  protected override string GetPrefix() {
    return "Derived2";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An override can call it's base function... you could then modify the base class to append the characters you want there.